# Modular Exponentiation in java (the algorithm gives a wrong answer)

Tags: java, modular, exponentiation

i am trying to implement the Modular Exponentiation but i can not get the right answer :

public static BigInteger modPow(BigInteger b, BigInteger e, BigInteger m)

{ //To Calculate the Modular Exponentiation And Return an object of BigInteger class

```
    BigInteger x= new BigInteger("1"); //The default value of x

    BigInteger power ;

    power=b.mod(m);

    String  t =e.toString(2); //convert the power to string of binary

    String reverse = new StringBuffer(t).reverse().toString();




    for (int i=0;i<reverse.length();i++ )  { //this loop to go over the string char by char by reverse

        if(reverse.charAt(i)=='1') { //the start of if statement when the char is 1
          x=x.multiply(power);
          x=x.mod(m);
          power=power.multiply(power);
          power=power.mod(m);

        } //the end of if statement



        }//the end of for loop


        return x;

    } //the end of the method modPow
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't do anything for exponent bits of zero. Won't you get the same results for an exponent of 2<sup>0</sup> and an exponent of 2<sup>2048</sup>?

These statements should come out of the `if` clause, and be executed on each iteration of the loop, whether the bit is zero or one:

```
power=power.multiply(power);
power=power.mod(m);
```

Also, iterating over the bits of the exponent using `e.testBit(i)` would be more efficient and easier to understand. Even if using `modPow()` is not allowed, `testBit()` should be okay.

---

Here's my version, including the fix for the bug and my suggestion to get rid of the string conversion. It also seems to work reliably for general numbers. It doesn't handle negative exponents and some other special cases.

```
public class CrazyModPow
{

  public static void main(String[] argv)
  {
    for (int count = 1; true; ++count) {
      Random rnd = new Random();
      BigInteger base = BigInteger.probablePrime(512, rnd);
      BigInteger exp = BigInteger.probablePrime(512, rnd);
      BigInteger mod = BigInteger.probablePrime(1024, rnd);
      if (!base.modPow(exp, mod).equals(modPow(base, exp, mod))) {
        System.out.println("base: " + base);
        System.out.println("exp:  " + exp);
        System.out.println("mod:  " + mod);
      }
      else if ((count % 10) == 0) {
        System.out.printf("Tested %d times.%n", count);
      }
    }
  }

  public static BigInteger modPow(BigInteger base, BigInteger e, BigInteger m)
  {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    base = base.mod(m);
    for (int idx = 0; idx < e.bitLength(); ++idx) {
      if (e.testBit(idx)) {
        result = result.multiply(base).mod(m);
      }
      base = base.multiply(base).mod(m);
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

Comment: That may be my favorite StackOverflow comment ever.

Comment: I HAVE TRIED A NUMBER WITH 512-BIT AND IT DID NOT WORK :(

Comment: @user2835815 I tested it with many different 512-bit exponents, and they all worked. What parameters did you try? What was the result?

Comment: i have used random class to generate the numbers(probabale prime)

Comment: it gives a number but it is not correct according to modpow in the class BigInteger if you compare it.

Comment: @user2835815 Well, if you applied the fix correctly, it should work. You'll have to provide a specific set of parameters for testing if you think it's still broken. I posted my code for comparison.